# Redis Cluster Key/Space event notifications

Tags: python, redis-cluster, redis-py

Official Redis documentation says - "Every node of a Redis cluster generates events about its own subset of the keyspace as described above. However, unlike regular Pub/Sub communication in a cluster, events' notifications are not broadcasted to all nodes. Put differently, keyspace events are node-specific. This means that to receive all keyspace events of a cluster, clients need to subscribe to each of the nodes."

I have used redis-py-cluster package and written the following code:

```
def test_pub_sub():
    pubsub = rs.pubsub()
    #pubsub.subscribe('music')
    pubsub.psubscribe('__key*__:*')
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        if message.get("type") == "message":
            print(message.get("data")) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rs = RedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True)
    test_pub_sub()
```

This is subscribing to the notification for a random node in a cluster. I want to listen to all nodes. How can i achieve this using redis-py-cluster package?